# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to \infty} (1+\sin 2x)^{\cot x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

Does this limit exist?

$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} (1+\sin 2x)^{\cot x}
$$
Thank you.

Comment: It does not. The function is periodic, and a non-constant periodic function necessarily fails to have a limit at $\infty$.

Comment: pretty sure it's already asked. Btw you find the limit, not the limit problem. Or you evaluate a limit. And this limit doesn't exist. It's an oscillatory limit. x should be tending to 0 not ∞

Comment: Are you sure that you look for $\lim_{x\to \infty}$ and not  $\lim_{x\to 0}$

Answer (score 0):

In case @ClaudeLeibovici is correct, and the limit is $0$, note that, $(1+\sin2x)>0 \ \forall \ x$, so you can write the expression as $L = e^{\log L}$ and, by Macalurin series expansion
$$
\log (1+ \sin 2x) \approx \sin 2x ,  x \to 0
$$
after a bit of algebra you'll get $e^2 ($i.e.$, \exp(2))$.